# I'm trying to run my program with Microsoft SQL with vb.net but I get an error message

Tags: vb.net

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
    Dim constring As String = "server=AZZAM-PC ; Database= FastFood ; integrated security=true"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constring)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("insert into tblsales (product , qunty , price )values(@product, @qunty, @price)", con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product", row.Cells("ITEM").Value)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qunty", row.Cells("QTY").Value)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", row.Cells("AMOUNT").Value)
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()

        End Using
    End Using
Next

MessageBox.Show("RECORD INSRTED")
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   Ooccurred in System.Data.dll
>   Additional information: The parameterized query '(@product
>   nvarchar(4000),@qunty nvarchar(4000),@price nvarchar(4' expects the
>   parameter '@product', which was not supplied.

Comment: Remove `.Value` from all your params;. Also on another note, dont' use `AddWithValue` it has to infer the datatype and they could be wrong, use `Add` and specify your datatype, length and the value.

Comment: The `For..Each` loop should be the inner block not the outer one. You should use the same `SqlConnection`, and for each iteration clear the command's parameters `cmd.Parameters.Clear` and set the new ones. Also, consider using [SqlTransaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Don't use a loop at all.  Create a `DataTable` and bind it to the grid, then use a data adapter to save the lot in one go.

Answer (score 1):

Don't keep adding the same parameters over an over. Add them once outside the loop and then just change the `Value` of the parameter inside the loop.

Use the `.Add` method for parameters. See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html

I had to guess at the datatypes in the database. Check your database and adjust the code accordingly.

```vb
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim constring As String = "server=AZZAM-PC ; Database= FastFood ; integrated security=true"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constring), 'note the comma, both con and cmd are included in the Using block
        cmd As New SqlCommand("insert into tblsales (product , qunty , price )values(@product, @qunty, @price)", con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@product", SqlDbType.VarChar, 300)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@qunty", SqlDbType.Int)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.Decimal)
        con.Open()
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
            cmd.Parameters("@product").Value = row.Cells("ITEM").Value.ToString
            cmd.Parameters("@qunty").Value = CInt(row.Cells("QTY").Value)
            cmd.Parameters("@price").Value = CDec(row.Cells("AMOUNT").Value)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    End Using 'Closes and disposes the connection and command
    MessageBox.Show("RECORDS INSRTED")
End Sub
```

Comment: All thanks to you But i have another problem with variable 'row' hides a variable in an enclosing block